# SVG linear gradient showing on one path but not the other

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, web

I have two paths that are incredibly similar except for the ending number in the d attribute. The first path displays correctly but the second path does not show up. What's weird is if I change the stroke of the second path to anything other than my defined gradient it'll appear. The gradient also appears if I truncate the decimals from the last number. Is there any reason why the second one doesn't appear with the gradient?

For what it's worth I'm trying to get this to work on google chrome.

```
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="pageSearchGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#a0c3d2" stop-opacity="0.75"></stop><stop offset="40%" stop-color="#F59B23" stop-opacity="0.85"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#F59B23" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg width="1600" height="500" class="sankey-diagram "><g width="1450" height="500" transform="translate(150, 0)"><g class="sankey-links">

    <!--  Only their decimal points differ for the last number and yet this one is the one that shows up -->
    <path d="M12,436.7529384197002C365.5,436.7529384197002,365.5,436.75293841969994,719,436.38406598523085" class="sankey-link " style="stroke: url(&quot;#pageSearchGradient&quot;); opacity: 0.3; stroke-width: 126.494;"></path>

    <path d="M12,436.7529384197002C365.5,436.7529384197002,365.5,436.75293841969994,719,436.75293841969994" class="sankey-link " style="stroke: url(&quot;#pageSearchGradient&quot;); opacity: 0.3; stroke-width: 126.494;"></path>

</svg>
```

Link to 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvEzNJ?editors=1000#0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference lies in the height of the bounding box for the two paths:

```
> document.querySelector('path:nth-child(1)').getBBox().height
> 0.368865966796875
> document.querySelector('path:nth-child(2)').getBBox().height
> 0
```

You are using percentage units for the gradient vector, and you are not specifying `gradientUnits`:

```
<linearGradient id="pageSearchGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
```

The [spec](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/pservers.html#LinearGradientElementGradientUnitsAttribute) has the following to say about these conditions:

> If **gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"**, the user coordinate system for attributes `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` is established using the bounding box of the element to which the gradient is applied and then applying the transform specified by attribute `gradientTransform`. Percentages represent values relative to the bounding box for the object.
>   When **gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"** and `gradientTransform` is the identity matrix, the normal of the linear gradient is perpendicular to the gradient vector in object bounding box space (i.e., the abstract coordinate system where (0,0) is at the top/left of the object bounding box and (1,1) is at the bottom/right of the object bounding box).

If that bounding box has no height, the top (defining 0 in bounding box space) and the bottom (defining 1) are the same value. It seems that browsers (and I can also see it in Firefox) get confused about that "abstract coordinate system" and no longer know how to compute the gradient vector and its normal.

I'd call that a bug. The best workaround I can come up with would be using `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, or making sure your path bounding box always has a non-zero width and height. (Threshold seems to lie around the seventh significant digit.)

Here is a test case showing the effect. There should be three rectangles, the first drawn with `<rect>`, the other two with `<line stroke-width=...>`. For the middle line, y1 and y2 are identical, for the bottom one they differ.

```html
<svg width="200" height="150">
  <linearGradient id="lg" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="0" />
    <stop stop-color="green" offset="1" />
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="5" y="0" width="200" height="40" style="fill:url(#lg)" />
  <line x1="0" y1="75" x2="200" y2="75" style="stroke-width:40;stroke:url(#lg)" />
  <line x1="0" y1="125" x2="200" y2="126" style="stroke-width:40;stroke:url(#lg)" />
</svg>
```